# Can not properly add an attribute with no value ('hidden') to an HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to dynamically add and remove the attribute hidden to some HTML elements with the following code:

```
<li><a href="#" onclick="SelectImage( 5 ); return false;">6</a></li>
...
<a href="/image/5"><img class="image_to_be_selected" id="image_5" hidden src="/img/5.jpg"></a>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#image_0').removeAttr( 'hidden' );
  function SelectImage( no ) {
    $('.image_to_be_selected').prop( 'hidden' );
    $('#image_'+no).removeAttr( 'hidden' );
  }
</script>
```

Main idea of this code is to remove the attribute 'hidden' from the first image at the beginning and upon `<li>` click hide all images and than to remove the property 'hidden' from the selected image.

But the code is not working properly: `$().prop()` doesn't add the attribute as desired. I should use `$().attr('hidden',true)` instead, but in this case the HTML will become as:

```
<a href="/image/5"><img class="image_to_be_selected" id="image_5" hidden='hidden' src="/img/5.jpg"></a>
```

(with extra ='hidden' chars)

Is it correct from the HTML validity POV?
Is there any function in JQuery to add an attribute with no value?

Comment: `hidden` is not a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML%2FGlobal_attributes), and is usually used with input-elements, not images. You should consider using the `data-*` attributes instead, if you need to keep this information as an attribute. Something like `data-hidden="true"`. If the attribute is used solely for styling purposes, consider making it a class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of adding and removing the hidden attribute, why not use jQuery .show() and .hide() instead?

```
$('#image_0').show();
  function SelectImage( no ) {
    $('.image_to_be_selected').hide();
    $('#image_'+no).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way is to use jquery [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to the elements of your choice.

```
$('#elementID').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your using `prop()` wrong. `prop('string')` is the **getter** `prop('string', value)` is the **setter**. You're using the getter and expecting it to set the value.

so

```
$('a').prop('hidden', true);
```

does

```
<a href="/image/5"><img class="image_to_be_selected" id="image_5" hidden src="/img/5.jpg"></a>
```

and

```
$('a').prop('hidden', false);
```

results in

```
<a href="/image/5"><img class="image_to_be_selected" id="image_5" src="/img/5.jpg"></a>
```

### [API docs here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Changing your code to:

```
$('#image_0').prop('hidden', true);
  function SelectImage( no ) {
    $('.image_to_be_selected').prop('hidden',  true);
    $('#image_'+no).prop('hidden', false);
  }
```

should result in the desired effect

Or do as Wbas says.....